# How to use focus() on QButton (<q-btn>)?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have a form developed in Quasar + Vue 3, and would like to programmatically set focus on the Submit button so that the user can press ENTER to submit.

```js
<q-btn ref="btn" />
```

I thought using refs would work:

```js
this.$refs.btn.focus()
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: this.$refs.btn.focus is not a function`.

How do I set focus on QButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the native DOM element by using `$el` and set `focus()` on that:

```js
this.$refs.btn.$el.focus()
```

Some Quasar component have built-in focus() methods, like QInput and QSelect, but QButton does not.

However, since the QButton component (`<q-btn>`) simply renders a `<button>` element as its root element, we can use Vue's [$el](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el) to retrieve it from the component instance (via `$refs`
), and then call the native JS function [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on that :)